# How are apps with typical menu-bar-style navigation coded?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I’m a relatively new app developer working on a couple of individual projects. I’ve dumped at least one hundred hours into coding using Swift in Xcode, and, as embarrassing as it may be to admit, it seems I can’t fully grasp or find information pertaining to how popular apps such as Facebook, Instagram, YouTube, or Tinder implement non-linear view navigation via a menu bar at the bottom of the screen.

I’ve seen one particular app tutorial series that exemplifies how to go about making this menu bar style possible using a collection view of horizontally-placed views each equivalent to the size of the screen. I understand this gets rid of the issue of loading new views on top of existing old ones that sit in the background (my primary worry, outside of unnecessarily reloading information), but is this the typical method of implementing non-linear menu navigation in an app? I suppose a more pressing question at this point is “How can I go about making something like this using SwiftUI?”

If anyone can offer information, explanations, and/or sources, they would all be much appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: "non-linear view navigation via a menu bar at the bottom of the screen" You mean like with a `UITabBar`/`UITabBarController`?

Comment: I’m trying to explain the menu bars popular apps have at the bottom of their view. Is the UITabBar/UITabBarController usually what’s used to make this?

Comment: @Vindog Yes, this is a [UITabBar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar).

Comment: Also, I haven't used a tab bar in SwiftUI yet, but this looks like a good tutorial for how to do it [here](https://www.iosapptemplates.com/blog/swiftui/tabview-swiftui).

Comment: Thank you for the comment, George_E! I had just found out about the TabView. This link looks like it will help very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, upon receiving TylerTheCompiler’s comment on my post, I started researching the UITabView. It appears that this is used for creating exactly what I was trying to explain in the initial post. I subsequently searched for a way to implement this in SwiftUI and found the “tabbed view.” The tabbed view seems very easy to implement and is exactly what I’ve been looking for. I still wonder if popular applications have been utilizing the UITabBar rather than something else more practical that I am still unaware of. If you happen to know, please comment on this post — I would love to know, myself. As always, thank you for your time, everyone!

Comment: The three apps you've mentioned are using custom implementations of a UITabBar/UIControl. Look into what is called 'subclassing' or 'extensions' in Swift for a better understanding of how they achieve such custom classes.